# Parallax background doesn't work (Only one image)

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, parallax

So I saw a nice background on http://terraria.org/about and thought by myself I want to that too since I run a Terraria Server.

So I have searched around the net for a function that could make this possible.
I have tried various things but this is the code I used:

```
link:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DCGuz
```

As you can see only the first image (which is on the top layer) moves, I was wondering how I could make all the images move as shown on http://terraria.org/about.
Also the background DOESN'T MOVE when I mouse over the logo or webpage itself while it SHOULD move
when I move my mouse over the website, it's not supposed to be a mouse-over image.

PS: When I try the moving background on my website (full screen) in my browser it's rather slow and doesn't move smooth, but it does move quick and smooth on terraria.org/about. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: As you can see on my website http://teeria.net/ only the first image moves, and it's not smooth.

Comment: Only the top most layer will receive mouse events. So you would need do all movement in the event listener of this layer.

Answer (score 0):

t.niese already said it: You create all these mouse-event handlers but only the topmost one gets called.

Instead, use `$(window).mousemove()` *once* and do all your stuff there. Also you repeatedly lookup the moving div with jQuery (every time the mouse moves) which might slow the animation down a bit.

You can save yourself quite a lot of typing/copying by using javascript closures: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Here's how it looks with the suggested changes: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgFhI

**Edit**: Make sure you are not violating any copyrights when using the image on your own website!

**Bonus-edit**: window.requestAnimationFrame is neat: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yEbnd

Comment: Ah yes I see it now, there is only one issue and that's the slowness of the movement and it's not smooth. I have also been trying another scripts but those only move sideways like I have tried this: http://codepen.io/stefanjudis/pen/nrzHI

Comment: But I couldn't really figure out how to make it work exactly like the background is now..

Comment: And yes, I will make sure I am not violating any copyrights :) but erh could you take a look at the script I send?

Comment: I did. [codepen.io/stefanjudis/pen/nrzHI]? There is no JS?

Comment: I have tried the code above which is: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBIar but there is one issue, it doesn't show as a background and is on http://teeria.net/ if you scroll all down, set as an image.

Comment: Yeah, but that's what user2202257 posted… I'm confused.

Comment: Yeah I am sorry I was trying to refer to what he posted, I am using his code now but now the issue I am having is that whenever I set the setting to 1920px 1080px, the images will become out of bounce as you can see on http://teeria.net/ and it's set as an image and not a background, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use CSS3. Basically you will need layers on top of layers. 
Check out 
Here-->https://github.com/abaddonGIT/paralax (translate to english)
demo-->http://angular.demosite.pro/paralax/
found here-->http://jqueryplugin.net/woolparalax-jquery-plugin-parallax-effect-css3/#sthash.XWD5Fr6P.uxfs

very simple
so it would be like

```
    window.onload = function () {
    $ ('# Wool-paralax). WoolParalax ();
    }
    <Div id = "wool-paralax">
    <div class="wool-layer" data-shift="0.02">
    <Img src = "img / 1.png" alt = "" />
    </div>
    <div class="wool-layer" data-shift="0.03">
    <Img src = "img / 2.png" alt = "" />
    </div>
    <div class="wool-layer" data-shift="0.04">
    <Img src = "img / 3.png" alt = "" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Okay I have got this working but there is only one issue as you can see on my website http://teeria.net/ the static background is shown and once you scroll down you will see the parallax effect (it's set as an image and not background?) and it's too small.